# UITableView delegate methods not getting called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a tab view with three different .xib files.  Each has its own controller and header files.  Two of them are almost identical.  So I copied the UI elements from one .xib file to the second and copied the code from one controller to the second.  Of course, changing controller names as necessary.  The first table gets displayed as expected.  The second does not get displayed at all.

Stepping through the code I can see where the delegate methods are getting called for the first one but they are not getting called for the second one.  It's like the code doesn't know to call these methods from that .xib file.  But I do have the UITableViewDelegate in my header file for that .xib.

Any ideas on what I have missed?

Thank you,
P

Comment: You say you have the delegate declaration in your header, but do you have a link between the table's delegate and dataSource properties and your controller?

Comment: Did you, in the .xib, connect the TableView Delegate and DataSource ?

Comment: OK.  I can see in the connections inspector that the datasource and delegate have been connected for the first .xib but not for the second one.  Not sure how to connect them.

Comment: I did it!!!!  Larme:  You're a genious!!!!  Thanks.  :-)

Comment: @Larme - Here I come back over a year later.  Now that I have become a more active member of SO, I would like to give you points for this answer.  So, give me an answer and I'll give you the points.